# Woocommerce: display custom text under products on checkout page based on shipping class

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce

I found this function that is working good on the cart page, but I also want to use it on the checkout page, what would I need to modify to make it work there? thanks in advance!

```html
// Display a custom text under cart item name in cart page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'custom_text_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );
function custom_text_cart_item_name( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    // Only on cart page
    if( ! is_cart() ) 
        return $item_name;

    // Here below define your shipping classes slugs (one by line)
    $shipping_class_1 = '5-gallon';
    $shipping_class_2 = '10-gallon';

    $shipping_class   = $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class();

    // First shipping class
    if( $shipping_class === $shipping_class_1 ) {
        $item_name .= '<br /><div class="item-shipping-class">' . __("Please call confirm shipping rates", "woocommerce") . '</div>';
    }
    // 2nd shipping class
    elseif( $shipping_class === $shipping_class_2 ) {
        $item_name .= '<br /><div class="item-shipping-class">' . __("Some different message…", "woocommerce") . '</div>';
    }

    return $item_name; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey why are you checking just for cart page if you want it on both the page?

Just check for both.

```php
if( ! ( is_cart() || is_checkout()) ) 
    return $item_name;
```

So the code becomes.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'bks_custom_text_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );
function bks_custom_text_cart_item_name( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

    if( ! ( is_cart() || is_checkout()) ) // CHANGE HERE
        return $item_name;


    $shipping_class_1 = '5-gallon';
    $shipping_class_2 = '10-gallon';

    $shipping_class   = $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class();

    if( $shipping_class === $shipping_class_1 ) {
        $item_name .= '<br /><div class="item-shipping-class">' . __("Please call confirm shipping rates", "woocommerce") . '</div>';
    }
    elseif( $shipping_class === $shipping_class_2 ) {
        $item_name .= '<br /><div class="item-shipping-class">' . __("Some different message…", "woocommerce") . '</div>';
    }

    return $item_name;
}
```

Screenshot of Checkout:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is just what I needed!